# How to make selenium cookies not expire? (python)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies, automated-tests, google-authentication

I'm using Selenium on Python 3,  to perform automated actions on an internal webpage on Chrome v81 browser, where google authentication (logging into gmail) is required.

**Getting cookies (after manually logging in):**
`pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open(path_to_cookie, 'wb'))`

**Using cookies:**

```
driver.get(url)
cookies = pickle.load(open(path_to_cookie, "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    if 'expiry' in cookie:  
        del cookie['expiry'] 
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
time.sleep(2)
driver.get(url)
```

**Problem:**
The cookies are stored in a pickle file. 
 There are 2 types of cookies - csrftoken and sessionid.
The sessionid one typically expires in 2 weeks, and **even if i change the expiry date of the cookies in the json (in the cookies.pkl file), it will still expire after 2 weeks** (and when i run the script it shows the gmail login page).

I've **tried using user-data-dir and chrome profile** (a duplicate of my existing chrome profile). 
It works, but the same problem still happens and i need to relogin again after 2 weeks. 
 Any idea how i can **make the cookies last for e.g months / a year instead of 2 weeks**?

Comment: the session token will expire server-side... then the refresh token is used to create a new one.  You have no control over the server-side expiration.  For Google I believe the refresh token never expires.

Comment: @pcalkins thanks for the comment. What's a refresh token? How do i get that? Or is that csrftoken

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem. Did you figure out a solution?